# Why would product description not transfer when doing an export and reimport from Magento 2 into a different Magento 2?

Tags: product, export, importexport, product-description

I have exported products from Magento 2.4.2-p1 and imported the file into Magento 2.4.5-p1.

I've noticed there are a lot of product descriptions missing when going through the products on Magento 2.4.5-p1. Why is that and how to fix? Does the Description also have specific requirements? (Alphanumeric, max number of characters etc. ?)